# How to interact with internal anchors and embedded hyperlinks of pdf

Tags: android, pdf, hyperlink, anchor, interactive

I am developing an application that can read PDF as well as it interact the hyperlink and internal anchors.
I am using MuPDF library, which is embedded in Android.
I am able to read the PDF file but how i can read and perform action on internal link and hyperlink?

Can anyone has an idea, how can i read the link and when use clicked on it, it open related page in PDF or in browser.

[MuPDF](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/list?q=source) link.